Is the pull back isomorphic to $O(1)$ on the projective space bundle?
The problem comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, II, Proposition 7.11.

Proposition 7.11. Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme. Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a locally free coherent sheaf on $X$. If $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ is the projective space bundle. (a) ...
(b) there is a natural surjective morphism $\pi^* (\mathcal{E}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(1)$.

I think the morphism in (b) is always an isomorphism. If not, is there any example?

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector bundle of rank $r$. In this case, $\Bbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ has fibres of dimension $r-1$. In the case where $r\ge 2$, we know that $\pi^*\mathcal{E}$ is also of rank $r\ge2$ and thus the map $\pi^*\mathcal{E}\to \mathcal{O}(1)$ can't be an isomorphism.
In the case where $\mathcal{E}$ is of rank $1$, the fibres are dimension zero and there is an isomorphism $\pi:\Bbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) \to X$. Since (by Hartshorne Prop. II.7.11) $\pi_*\mathcal{O}(1) = \mathcal{E}$, in this case the morphism is an isomorphism.
In short, when the projective bundle construction is interesting, the morphism $\pi^*\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{O}(1)$ is not an isomorphism.
